# AWS amplify server-only implementation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

We have a unity game under development and we need to set up GraphQL API endpoints for being used in our frontend game.
The server(TS) and frontend (Unity) teams are completely separate teams.

There are tons of resources on how to develop a full-stack app for instance via react and Amplify, Cognito, etc., but what if the backend team needs to develop a "Server only" implementation and be able to generate API docs for the separate client team to implement them in their frontend developments?